# Finding a good DB design for my project

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I'm really struggling to find a good DB design for my project using SQL server.

I've already implemented a few models which worked great till this point, but now that I need to add something extra I just can't find a good option and I'm stuck with it ATM.

I've supplied below 2 very simplified models (class diagrams) I've tried, but both models are not working well.

**1st model:** which I also prefer if it's possible to fix

[image: 1st model]

I should explain first that msg and action can have the same basic id (i.e 1) but when used with tabID or groupID as a composite primary key, it becomes unique.

Here you can see that `UserInput` is created using only the basic ID which creates a problem to save both a `Msg` and `Action` with id 1 for example.
Is there anyway around this? maybe a way to say that ya `Action` and `Msg` are extending `UserInput` but they define all the keys themselves?

**2nd model:**

[image: class diagram]

Each `Critical Point` is related to either a `Msg` or `Action`, but how can I define it since they have a different set of PK? I would like to keep referral integrity.

I would REALLY appreciate help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Potential fix for 1st model**

I do not understand why `Action` and `Msg` can have the same id. If you want to treat them both similarly (as `UserInput`) then the id of the `UserInput` table needs to be unique for them both. So each id of `UserInput` represents either an `Action` or a `Msg`.

I do not know if this is a good example, but lets if `Action` and `Msg` are similar to `Car` and `Motorcycle`, than you still want to be able to uniquely identify them so their id on the license plate should really be unique and thus should not exist in both groups.

Does the critical point needs to know by what it is used?
If not, you just need a foreign key column "CriticalPointId" in your `UserInput` class. Because `Action` and `Msg` are subclasses, they can both access their `CritialPoint`.

**Potential fix for 2nd model**

In this model you have unique ids in the `Msg` and `Action` table.
In that respect, it is very similar to my proposed fix for the first model, expect from that fact that no `UserData` table exists.

This might be the better solution if `Msg` and `Action` do not have anything in common (there are no properties in `UserData` in the first model except from the ID).

Supposing that the `CriticalPoint` does not need to know by what object it is used, you just need to specify a "CriticalPointId" foreign key column in both the `Msg` and the `Action` table.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree with you that `Msg` & `Action` should have a unique identifier between them, but I'm getting the data from an external API so I need to work with what I got. I can't change the API and I also don't want to change the keys. I could have fixed it by changing the key to be for example `action-201-213` which is built from the `[Action|Msg]-[Tab|GroupID]-[UserInputID]`. but again this is not a good solution for me.

Comment: For you 2nd proposal, The id's here are again not unique, but the composite primary key are.
This fix is a good idea if I want to navigate from the action\msg to the critical point. but what if I want to go the other way around? I have to join 3 tables (action, msg, critical)  in-order to get the msg\action that triggered the critical point.

Comment: you suggestion are good. so I gave you the +1. but I chose a different model. which is much simpler - just added 2 type of critical points. I handle the connection between them in my code.

Comment: Does all the data come from the external API or just `Msg` and `Action`? Perhaps you can keep the id of the external system (column "ExternalId")´and just use it as reference and add an additional id of your own in `UserInput` which you have control over.

Comment: just `Msg` and `Action`. I thought about that also, but it will require me to keep an extra index. (prefer not to).

Again I appreciate your input but I've already changed the model to something that works for me.